# All data in one column

Tags: r

I have this soccer data all in one column.

```
Round 36  # Round of the league------------------------------------

29.07. 20:45   # Date and time of the match

Barcelona       # Home Team

4 - 1           # FT result

Getafe          # Away team

(2 - 0)         # HT result

29.07. 20:45   # *date of the second match of the round*

Valencia

2 - 3

Laci

(1 - 2)

Round 35  # repeating pattern -------------------------------------------------
```

How can I move all the data in a certain round of the league in a new column? e.g. I want all observation from the **Round 36** observation to the **Round 35** observation in a single a column and so on.

I really do not have any idea how to solve this. I tried to transpose the data so that I could work better with observations as variables but still nothing. I am just a beginner in R and would appreciate any help.
thanks

Comment: You will have to read the data into R using `readLines()`. It will be simpler to split into columns if the number of lines between rounds is the same. If not, you will have to check each line for "Round" and then process the following lines until the next "Round".

Comment: No, the number of the lines is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is within a variable named `lines` (eg, `lines[1] = Round 36` is the first entry, `lines[2] = 29.07. 2045` is the next entry and so forth), we can spot the lines, split the vector into a list and then finally bind it into a `data.frame` (assuming they have equal length, if not you will have to do some manual work)

```
#Figure out where each round is.
rounds <- grepl('^Round', lines) 
# Split it into seperate list. cumsum(rounds) will be an index for each group.
data <- split(lines, cumsum(rounds))
# Bind the data into a data.frame (assuming all have the same amount of data) 
bound <- do.call(rbind, data)
```

Of course without a reproducible example it is hard to test the final result.
**Note** that if the soccer data does not have equal amount of data between rounds **or** if the data does not come in the same order, the resulting `data.frame` may not make immediate sense (if round 45 has 7 elements but round 46 has 4, round 46 will recycle element 1, 2 and 3 to fill out the missing values), but it might make it simpler to do some follow up data cleaning.